# Clarification regarding SOC-2 compliance in multiple locations

Tags: security, standards-compliance

I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question.

We are a startup having customers in 4 different locations. Our customers are being served from cloud - hosted in 4 different data centers in different locations. We have a requirement of SOC-2 for the customers of a particular location e.g. customers of USA.

Is it possible to keep the scope of SOC-2 to US data centers? It is hard for us to prepare ourselves for all data center at this stage of the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have confirmed this with our auditors that scope can be limited to one location.